# Rails Skinny controllers, fat models - need more help achieving it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I'm trying to make my controllers skinnier. To achieve this, most of my efforts went on building named_scopes, etc.

Should this kind of code be in the model, and if so, how?

```
def show
  ### params[:date] = {"month"=>"2", "year"=>"2012"}
  @date = Time.parse(params[:date][:month] + '/' + params[:date][:year])
  ...
end
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with that being in the controller.

Comment: Longer answer: Don't get too hung up on skinny controllers.  If you don't have business logic in there, you should be fine.  What you're doing here is just prepping a var for the view.  It's where it should be.

Comment: That code is fine in the controller as long as it's just creating a date object with which to act on. If however, you start formatting the date strings in the controller, that's something that's view specific and should be placed in a helper method.

Comment: Guys, if you're going to downvote a question tell the person asking why... if you're opinion is the person asking should take a different approach or shouldn't be concerned with what they are doing then say it but that isn't really a good reason to downvote the question itself when the question itself appears to be valid

Comment: Thanks guys, now it's clearer for me what should go in the model and what should really be in the controller! 
I'm sorry if my question was a bit misleading, it was meant to be a 2-part question, 1 - if that code should be in the model and 2 - if it should be in the model, how should I put it there! My bad!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the thinnest you could be, but it would be more elegant and re-usable if you can get this time parser in to a helper methods.

** helpers can be called from controllers as well. Something like this in your helper:

```
def time_parser(month, year)
  Time.parse(month + '/' + year)
end
```

and in your controller

```
def show
  ### params[:date] = {"month"=>"2", "year"=>"2012"}
  @date = time_parser(params[:date][:month],params[:date][:year])
  ...
end
```